# Flutter WebView with WillPopScope not working as expected

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I have implemented Flutter Webview using **[webview_flutter: ^0.3.3](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter)** dependency.

My flow is:

**Splash Screen -> Home Page (2 buttons, Login and Explore) -> Login Page**

if already pressed Login once then it will open `LoginPage` directly.

Let me share code:

**splash_screen.dart**

```
  Future<void> doSomeAsyncStuff() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    isLogin = prefs.getBool('isLogin') ?? false;

    new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => isLogin ? LoginPage() : HomePage()));
    });
  }
```

**home_page.dart**

```
  // Login Button Click, Here I am saving preference for login.
  // So I can come to login directly when I open the app.
  Future<void> openLoginPage() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setBool('isLogin', true);
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()));
  }

  // Explore Button Click
  void openExplorePage() {
    Navigator.push(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ExplorePage()));
  }
```

**login_page.dart**

```
// I AM GETTING PROBLEM HERE...
// WHEN I AM PRESSING BACK BUTTON.. I WANT TO EXIT FROM APP BUT BECAUSE OF THERE IS NOTHING IN BACK STACK, IT IS NOT DOING ANYTHING.
// IF I HAVE SOMETHING IN BACK STACK OF WEBVIEW, IT WILL GO TO BACK PAGE but PROBLEM IS ONLY WHEN I WANT TO EXIT FROM APP.
Future<bool> _exitApp(BuildContext context) async {
  if (await controllerGlobal.canGoBack()) {
    controllerGlobal.goBack();
  } else {
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
    return Future.value(true);
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

In SplashScreen you have used `Navigator.push()` to move to the login screen so it have SplashScreen on the back stack. Use Navigator.pushReplacement instead of Navigator.push() it will replace the previous screen.

```
new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => isLogin ? LoginPage() : HomePage()));
    });
```

Comment: After using `Navigator.pushReplacement`, Its giving me blank screen because there will be nothing in stack.